# T-SQl: помогите оптимизировать запрос с функциями

Tags: sql, sql-server, оптимизация

Добрый день.

Ниже представлен текст запроса, он дает правильные результаты, но выполняется слишком долго. Прошу помочь его оптимизировать (это моя последняя и актуальная версия запроса.):

```
  DECLARE @dateFrom datetime = @filter.value('(FilterSet/items[@name="dateFrom"])[1]', 'datetime');
  DECLARE @dateTo datetime = @filter.value('(FilterSet/items[@name="dateTo"])[1]', 'datetime');

  DECLARE  @costTable table (providerName varchar(50), clientName varchar(50),messageId int, [count] int, cost numeric(18,3),  [month] date )

  INSERT @costTable
  SELECT 
    p.providerName,
    c.clientName,    
    m.messageId,  
    [dbo].[func_GetSmsCount] (m.messageId, m.[recipient], p.providerId, m.dt, ms.statusValue),
    [dbo].[func_GetSmsCost] (m.messageId, m.[recipient], p.providerId, m.dt, ms.statusValue),
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, m.[dt]), 0) as DT 
  FROM [dbo].[Messages] (NOLOCK) m
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[MessageStatus] (NOLOCK) ms
    ON m.messageId = ms.messageId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Clients] (NOLOCK) c
    ON m.clientId = c.clientId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Debtors] (NOLOCK) d
    ON c.debtorId = d.debtorId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Providers] (NOLOCK) p
    ON ms.providerId = p.providerId

  WHERE  ms.statusId = 2 AND p.isEmail != 1 
    AND CAST(m.dt as date) >= @dateFrom AND CAST(m.dt as date) <= @dateTo    
    AND  ((ms.[providerId] = 6) OR (ms.[providerId] = 2) OR (ms.[providerId] = 1) )
  GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, m.[dt]), 0), p.providerName, c.clientName, m.messageId, m.[recipient], p.providerId, m.dt,
  [dbo].[func_GetSmsCount] (m.messageId, m.[recipient], p.providerId, m.dt, ms.statusValue), 
  [dbo].[func_GetSmsCost] (m.messageId, m.[recipient], p.providerId, m.dt, ms.statusValue)

    SELECT 
    [month],
    providerName,
    SUM(cost) as [summ], 
    COUNT(cost) as [smsCount], 
    COUNT(1) [TotalCount], 
    COUNT(1) - COUNT(cost) as [ErrorCount],
    SUM([count]) as partCount
  FROM @costTable
    GROUP BY [month], providerName
    ORDER BY  [month] desc, providerName
```

Спасибо.

План выполнения (кусок с максимальным значением):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К стати, я построил индекс по тем полям, но мне все равно пишет создать тот индекс. Может быть, потому что уже был до этого создан некластерный индекс по полю "recipient" ?

Comment: Я бы, наверное, начал с того, что внутри `func_GetSmsCount` и `func_GetSmsCost`. Может быть можно объединить две эти скалярные функции в одну inline-табличную. Также, если в `Providers` и `Clients` нет записей с одинаковыми именами, но разными `Id`, то лучше группировать по их `Id`, а не по именам, а `Providers` и `Clients` присоединять к уже сгруппированным данным. Затем, быть может, посмотреть на предмет недостающих индексов.

Answer (score 3):

Зачем вы предварительную выборку пихаете в таблицу-переменную?
Этим вы принуждаете сервер запихать кучу строк в оперативную память(или в tempdb, если первая закончится)

В даннном случае это действие бессмысленно и вредно.

Что же касается оптимизации запроса, попробуйте поиграться с порядком таблиц в предложении `FROM`, приписав опцию `FORCE ORDER`(которая заставляет оптимизатор выбрать пользовательский порядок соединения строк).

**И обязательно уберите из группировки функции. У вас функция выполняется для каждой строки! Они походу всё портят..**
Достаточно добавить группировку по ms.statusValue, **а функции убрать!**

Будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
DECLARE @dateFrom datetime = @filter.value('(FilterSet/items[@name="dateFrom"])[1]', 'datetime');
  DECLARE @dateTo datetime = @filter.value('(FilterSet/items[@name="dateTo"])[1]', 'datetime');

  ;WITH costTable AS(
  SELECT 
    p.providerName,
    c.clientName,    
    m.messageId,  
    [dbo].[func_GetSmsCount] (m.messageId, m.[recipient], p.providerId, m.dt, ms.statusValue) as [count],
    [dbo].[func_GetSmsCost] (m.messageId, m.[recipient], p.providerId, m.dt, ms.statusValue) as cost,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, m.[dt]), 0) as [month] 
  FROM [dbo].[Messages] (NOLOCK) m
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[MessageStatus] (NOLOCK) ms
    ON m.messageId = ms.messageId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Clients] (NOLOCK) c
    ON m.clientId = c.clientId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Debtors] (NOLOCK) d
    ON c.debtorId = d.debtorId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Providers] (NOLOCK) p
    ON ms.providerId = p.providerId

  WHERE  ms.statusId = 2 AND p.isEmail != 1 
    AND CAST(m.dt as date) >= @dateFrom AND CAST(m.dt as date) <= @dateTo    
    AND  ((ms.[providerId] = 6) OR (ms.[providerId] = 2) OR (ms.[providerId] = 1) )
  GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, m.[dt]), 0), p.providerName, c.clientName, m.messageId, m.[recipient], p.providerId, m.dt,ms.statusValue
  )
    SELECT 
    [month],
    providerName,
    SUM(cost) as [summ], 
    COUNT(cost) as [smsCount], 
    COUNT(1) [TotalCount], 
    COUNT(1) - COUNT(cost) as [ErrorCount],
    SUM([count]) as partCount
  FROM costTable
    GROUP BY [month], providerName
    ORDER BY  [month] desc, providerName

  OPTION(FORCE ORDER)
```

Если же группировка по `ms.statusValue` недопустима(тут зависит от вашей задачи). То добавьте `DISTINCT` в СТЕ `costTable`(добавив туда все поля, которые были в группировке в первоначальном запросе). Это даст точно такой же результат, как ваш первоначальный запрос на любых данных.
Но мне что-то подсказывает, что этот `DISTINCT` всё же лишний.

Можете ещё попытаться поиграться с хинтами LOOP; HASH в соединениях. Но это лучше делать если у вас есть определённый опыт.

Answer (score 0):

Без описания функции **[dbo].[func_GetSmsCount]** ничем вам помочь не смогут (пишу в виде ответа, т.к. не хватает репутации для комментария, если еще актуально можете написать в личку, думаю смогу помочь).